# How do you get an hourly talking clock?

Tags: software-recommendation, clock

I want to get a program (a script that can be set to auto-start or something) that tells you every hour like "It's 11 o'clock."

I know it's easy on Macs, but how do you get that on Precise?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's a program in the standard repos for it, `saytime`.

`sudo apt-get install saytime`

Then you can run `saytime -r 3600` to run it every hour (3600 seconds, or change the number for a different interval in seconds). It will start as a background process when run with this option.

If you want to change the format (for example to remove the "and X seconds") it would be `saytime -r 3600 -f %P%l%M` - full format options in `man saytime`.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=516600&p=3130400#post3130400

Comment: @Dan Wow. Whoops. Good spot, that's rather an embarrassing one! Yes, it was indeed meant to be 3600. Edited to fix.

Comment: If you have problems like `sox FAIL formats: can't open output file '/dev/audio': Permission denied` run it with `padsp`: `$ padsp saytime -r 3600`

Comment: @franzlorenzon How do you make `padsp saytime -r 3600` work from Startup Applications in Gnome? I tried adding it there but it doesn't work.

Comment: Does it work one the terminal? Can you see the log from Gnome (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17244/where-is-log-file-of-gnome-3)?

Comment: How can I use this to run at starting of every hour like 1 o' clock, 2 o' clock, etc...?

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install festival
```

If you wanna get crazy you can also add to gnome-schedule:

```
echo This is my custom message | festival --tts
```

Where custom message can include the output of the command

```
date
```

and if you want a nicer voice try something like:

```
sudo apt-get install festvox-us1
echo "(set! voice_default 'voice_us1_mbrola)" | sudo tee -a /etc/festival.scm
```

Comment: I think you should use cron too to make it run every hour.

Comment: That's what I meant by gnome-schedule

Comment: Ops, you're right :)

Answer (score 0):

The current espeak version (1.48.3) links directly to mbrola voices. So you can obtain a good result with something like:

```
date|espeak -v en-us
```

Parms are available to espeak to tweak the voice. See it's `man` for more options.